# Page refresh on Button Click only during Ajax POST request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am a beginner in web dev and building a simple query-answer web app in which User enters the query in the text field and clicks on the button, JavaScript sends the POST request to server and server sends back the response. Now this response should be displayed on the screen till the user enters a new query and clicks on the button again.

This is the client side code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $.post("ServletServer", {
            Query: document.getElementById("query").value
        },
        function(data, status) {
            var json_x = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(json_x, function(index, element) {
                $('#Results').append($('<div>', {
                    text: index+" "+element.URI
                }));
            });
        });
    });
});
```

When I tried to use window.location.reload() mentioned in some previous questions, like this:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    window.location.reload()
});
```

It refreshes the page just after displaying the response. I want the response to stay on the page till user again clicks on the button. Can anybody please tell me where I am going wrong

Comment: So the same button performs an ajax call and refreshes the page?

Comment: @Tsalikidis Yeah, I dont want a separate button for refreshing the page, the same button will clear the results and will show the new results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the results div before doing the POST request with `$('#Results').html("");`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $('#Results').html(""); // clears the results, then does the ajax request.

        $.post("ServletServer",
            {
                  Query: document.getElementById("query").value
            },
            function(data, status){
                doRequest = false; // update flag
                var json_x = $.parseJSON(data);
                $.each(json_x, function(index, element) {
                    $('#Results').append($('<div>', {
                        text: index+" "+element.URI
                   }));
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: In this case first the page will reload after clicking the button and then if we click the button again only then it will display the new results. I want these two things to happen simultaneously

Comment: I guess I don't get what you want, but I made a more specific example in http://jsfiddle.net/95kpdgh3/ hope it helps

Comment: I saw your last comment, you want to clear the results before to display the new ones..

Comment: I updated the answer to clear the results before the ajax request.